# HTML <video> not working in chrome. Two http requests, the second one with size 0

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I'm trying to display a local .mp4 video with html , but I'm not able to get it working in Chrome.

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="/uploads/video/2015/10/562b8c42e64d9.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

In Firefox works great. Checking the network section in dev-tools I've noticed that there's two requests instead of one, and the last one shows size 0:

```
562b8c42e64d9.mp4   200 media   Other   78.8 MB 823 ms  
562b8c42e64d9.mp4   200 media   Other   0 B 3 ms
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you set the src directly to the `<video>` element? Also, what's the media's codec?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to play it locally, without a server, it must use the "file" protocol. Therefore your source must be

```
src="file:///uploads/video/...."
```

On a Unix-like system, you will need to do it this way:

```
src="file:///home/me/uploads/video/...."
```

or similar to make sure the path is complete.

Also, `source` does not have a closing slash.

Comment: Actually I just tried and if the page was served within the `file` protocol, and the `src` set with a relative path (as OP does), the `file` protocol should be used by default. Also, source is on the list of self-closing tags, so OP's code is right.

Comment: @Kaiido It does not work on my BSD system without the full path or at least needs a dotted path. Self closing means it doesn't need an end tag. The HTML spec does not call out a closing slash for the source element and a  closing slash is not needed on any self closing tag.

Comment: If it was the problem, Firefox would encounter the same. Misread about the end tag note : I thought you told him that there is no end tag in his markup, my bad. But anyway, source is a "void" element, and [according to the specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag), for void elements, "there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character (/)." so this might not be its problem either. But without more info form OP, we can only make blind guesses like this and it's improbable that we do find the solution to his problem.

Comment: @Kaiido Void elements are exceptions to the rule and the rule, as stated in the spec, is that source tags do not need a closing slash. The rule for void tags states that you can put one there but browsers must ignore it. So it serves no purpose. His problem doesn't show up for me in Firefox so,  I agree, I think his problem is something we're not seeing.

Comment: Has this ever been fixed? I have exactly the same issue with one of my videos :(